# Integrate iphone camera into ViewController's subview UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am using following code to embed Camera into my application view.

Here is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;

    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];

    captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = self.cameraView.bounds;
    [self.cameraView.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];

    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    NSError *error = nil;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
    if (!input)
    {
        [Utilities alertDisplay:@"Error" message:@"Camera not found. Please use Photo Gallery instead."];
    }

    [session addInput:input];

    stillImageOutput = [[AVCaptureStillImageOutput alloc] init];
    NSDictionary *outputSettings = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: AVVideoCodecJPEG, AVVideoCodecKey, nil];
    [stillImageOutput setOutputSettings:outputSettings];

    [session addOutput:stillImageOutput];

    [session startRunning];
}

-(AVCaptureDevice *)backFacingCameraIfAvailable{

    NSArray *videoDevices = [AVCaptureDevice devicesWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    AVCaptureDevice *captureDevice = nil;

    for (AVCaptureDevice *device in videoDevices){

        if (device.position == AVCaptureDevicePositionBack){

            captureDevice = device;
            break;
        }
    }

    //  couldn't find one on the front, so just get the default video device.
    if (!captureDevice){

        captureDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    }

    return captureDevice;
}


- (IBAction)scanButtonPressed:(id)sender
{
    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in stillImageOutput.connections)
    {
        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts])
        {
            if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo] )
            {
                videoConnection = connection;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (videoConnection) { break; }
    }

    NSLog(@"about to request a capture from: %@", stillImageOutput);
    [stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error)
     {
         CFDictionaryRef exifAttachments = CMGetAttachment( imageSampleBuffer, kCGImagePropertyExifDictionary, NULL);
         if (exifAttachments)
         {
             // Do something with the attachments.
             NSLog(@"attachements: %@", exifAttachments);
         }
         else
             NSLog(@"no attachments");

         NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
         UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

         //self.vImage.image = image;
     }];
}
```

The problem i am facing is, I don't get any camera opened in my cameraView and also on scanBtnPressed i get

```
stillImageOutput.connections = 0 objects.
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I just copy pasted your code into a blank project and it worked fine when changing `self.cameraView.layer` to `self.view.layer`. However, I did try creating `self.cameraView` and never initializing it and it had similar consequences to those you described.

Overall, I would check to make sure that `self.cameraView` isn't nil. If it's done programmatically, make sure you're calling alloc/init and setting a frame, and if it's an IBOutlet make sure it's properly linked.

Comment: oh man, i didn't attach the cameraView with Its Outlet on Xib :) Thanks worked atlast.. wasted two hours on coding..

Comment: @MuhammadUmar Man I know the feeling. Glad it helped!